# Angular Routing with UI-route issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im new at Angular and I've been following [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/). Everything was going good and until I reach the part where Angular Routing was supposed to happened. I could not find the error. If anybody could give me a hand that wold be great!
Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xWvHs1ClbTvv6UGYQoyT?p=preview).

Here's the app (app3.js):

```
var app = angular.module('futbol', ['ui.router'])        
    app.factory('jugadores', [function(){
      var o = {
        jugadores: []
        /*jugadores: [
          {nombre: 'Hernan', goles: 5},
          {nombre: 'Ricardo', goles: 2},
          {nombre: 'Tiago', goles: 15},
          {nombre: 'Marcelo', goles: 9},
          {nombre: 'German', goles: 4}
        ];*/
      };
      return o;
    }])
    app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'jugadores',
    function($scope,jugadores){
        $scope.jugadores = jugadores.jugadores;
        $scope.test = 'HOLA!';
        $scope.addJugador = function(){
          $scope.jugadores.push({nombre: $scope.nombre, goles: 0});
          $scope.nombre = '';
        };
        $scope.incrementGoles = function(jugador) {
          jugador.goles += 1;
        };
    }]);
    app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: '/home.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }]);
```

Go to plunker link to see the HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [updated and running plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tj4iEOFeHsHOG7qI5PZy?p=preview)

To make it running we need a root anchor/target **`ui-view=""`** for our state:

```
<body ng-app="futbol">  

    <div ui-view=""></div>
```

And also, this should be the otherwise *(not just 'home')*:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

It says which url should be used as default...

Comment: Thank you! So simple... This will help me a lot!

Comment: Great to see that sir ;) Enjoy might UI-Router ;)

Comment: Im getting the $scope.nombre undefined though :(

Comment: You should learn much more, I'd say ;) but do not give up. In this case, do not use ui-view element at all. It just breaks scopes. Check it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/cKvwMwqghLDAEOjM8bwk?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I should! I am a total rookie! Thank you sir for your time, very helpfull